# html tabindex property

Tags: jquery, html

i have a form. which includes menubar, corporation icon, some links, and 10 input[type='text']. i have writen tabindex attribute only for 5 inputs. because i want to make so that only this five input can be focused. how i can do it?

Comment: -1? why? it was simple question or what else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`tabindex` sets the indexing order of items, but it does not set a limit on which elements can be focused.

You should be able to achieve what you want by giving the last input the following JavaScript:

```
<input onblur="$('#firstitem').focus();">
```

or alternatively, in the `ready()` block

```
$("#lastitem").blur(function() { $('#firstitem').focus(); })
```

keep in mind though that with that, you are taking away the user's ability to navigate the page using a keyboard.

Comment: yesss. greate. simple. but did not think. i know i will taking away the user's ability to navigate the page using keyboard. but only in this page. :-) i searched for it. thanks..

Answer (score 6):

Approach 1: Harmful with relatively weak browser support (it depends on the [HTML5 draft](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/editing.html#sequential-focus-navigation-and-the-tabindex-attribute))

Set a negative tabindex value on every element you do not wish to get the focus.

This will render it impossible for some users (especially screen reader users who have a higher portion of non-mouse users among them) to access those elements of the page.

Approach 2: Equally harmful but with relatively high browser support.

Bind, using JavaScript, an `onfocus` event handler to every element that you don't want to receive the focus. Have it call the `focus()` method of the first form control.

**Doing either of these is a user-hostile act. Don't do it.**